# VBA vbNewLine but with no extra space

Tags: vba, excel

I'm adding a Title to a chart but I keep getting an extra space (white space) between the two strings when I use vbNewLine.

```
myChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Distance to Default for" & vbNewLine & compName
```

note `compName` is another string I previously define.

Comment: You're not getting an extra space. It just looks like a space. If you copy that space and paste it into a text area, it'll be treated like a new line. I personally don't know what's causing this. I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably it's a text format issue. Try: `vbCrLf`, `vbCr`, `vbLf` or (digged up the doc) `Environment.NewLine`. One of the four should be OK.
"Cr" is "carriage return" while "Lf" is "Line Feed" (these terms come from old typewriter times). Some OS/text format/system/whatever uses both "driver characters", some use just one of these - the white space you saw was an unnecessary "cr" or "lf" if that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Try vbCrLf:

```
myChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Distance to Default for" & vbCrLf & compName
```

EDIT: Try `vbCr` since `vbCrLf` looks to be identical to `vbNewline`

```
myChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Distance to Default for" & vbCr & compName
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess. I always use vbCrLf so I thought it might be different. Now I see they are same. Weird it causes extra line.

Answer (score 1):

helpful post. I have the same issue. "text" & vbnewline & "text" is two carriage returns instead of one...
vbVerticalTab worked well for me.

Comment: That helped in my case. Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what end result you're aiming for, but using vbNewLine will insert a carriage return.

If you're just trying to insert a space between the text and the value then one of the following would work:

`myChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Distance to Default for " & compName`

`myChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Distance to Default for" & Chr(32) & compName`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The person wants a newline but is getting a space between the newline and the string.

Answer (score 0):

So here's my solution. Use `chr(10)` instead of `vbNewLine` and then do this:

`compName = Replace(compName, vbCrLf, Chr(10))`

It worked for me. Don't know if it'll work for everyone. Cheers.

Comment: I think char(10) is pc and you'd need char(13) for mac

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `vbVerticalTab` or `Chr(11)`. This is the same as hitting `shift` + `enter` if you were typing a Word document.

Interestingly, in the Official documentation, [VBA Miscellaneous constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/miscellaneous-constants), it says this in the description:

> Not useful in Microsoft Windows or on the Macintosh

Of which I disagree. The documentation says the same thing about `vbFormFeed` / `Chr(12)`, but you can use that to easily insert page breaks.